# Need to Create a Windows and Web-based version of the same app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows

Is there a wrapper or framework that can easily convert or run a MVC web app as a windows based app or vice versa? One version needs to run in a browser, and the other standalone.

Seems kind of a niche and pointless thing but this is a bit of an awkward problem. With some planning I can probably maximize code reuse, but there's still going to be a lot of almost duplicate but slightly different code writing needed. Any ideas?

Comment: Load the web page in a web browser control ?

Comment: This sounds like [Hosted Web Apps](https://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/HWA.htm) for Windows 10. If you are OK with deploying your application as a UWP you may be able to package it as an HWA

Comment: *"Is there a wrapper or framework that can easily convert or run a MVC web app as a windows based app **or vice versa**?"* Not sure, what that is supposed to mean. You want to turn your Windows (Desktop) application to run as an MVC web app? This isn't going to happen, unless you severely restrict, what your Windows (Desktop) app is allowed to do. It doesn't sound like you really thought this through anyway.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have mentioned MVC, a generic web app would've made more sense I guess. There's no existing application yet, so I can start with either a web app or desktop app. Looking for the best way to do both, without doing them completely independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option would be to implement your MVC application and then use [Hosted Web Apps](https://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/HWA.htm) approach to create Windows 10 app. Basically it will be your website in an application window, and you can implement many Windows Store features on top of it like for instance in-app purchases. It will look and feel like a native app.

From the website

> For existing web applications, Windows 10 makes it easy for you to
>   create a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app that packages your
>   website for publishing to the Store.

They promise:

- Look great across all Windows-based devices, including PCs, tablets, phones, HoloLens, Surface Hub, Xbox and Raspberry Pi.
- Update and call native Windows APIs from JavaScript running on your website, creating a more engaging user experience.
- Integrate with Cortana voice commands.
- Debug your app with Microsoft Edge F12 Developer Tools.
- Track status, ratings, and reviews, see analytics, and get paid for all of your Windows app in the Windows Store.

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks!